# jquery window.resize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

Guys i wrote a very simple jquery script to place elements properly on a webpage,  basically making it responsive without media queries. Now it works just fine but the window.resize is not triggering so on document.ready it works on window resize it does not. Any help would be highly appreciated. Putting the link to the page at the bottom

```
    // JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(PlaceContents);
$(window).ready(PlaceContents);
$(window).on('resize',PlaceContents);

function PlaceContents() {                

        var Wheight = $(document).height();
        var Wwidth = $(document).width();
        var contentPos = Wwidth/4;
        var contentH = Wheight/5;


        //adjust menubar height
        $('#menubar').height(Wheight);

        //center main content
        $("#maincontent").css({top: contentH, left: contentPos, position:'absolute'});


};
```

http://www.mobileapplicationlabs.com/goldentreehotels/

Comment: `basically making it responsive without media queries` Why would you want to do that? Media queries were invented for this purpose. Javascript should not be a crutch for UI amendments.

Comment: I think there is also jquery conflicts

Comment: @Rory McCrossan be vertical aligned properly even though its inline-block. Tried  because if you see the design the right side content box needs to be vertical aligned properly even though its inline-block. Tried tons of stuff but didnt work. Vertical-align:middle has always been an issue. That was one of the reasons of jquery usage

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    PlaceContents();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do callback on this:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  PlaceContents();
 });


 function PlaceContents() {                
         var Wheight = $(document).height();
         var Wwidth = $(document).width();
         var contentPos = Wwidth/4;
         var contentH = Wheight/5;


         //adjust menubar height
         $('#menubar').height(Wheight);

         //center main content
         $("#maincontent").css({top: contentH, left: contentPos, position:'absolute'});


 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="maincontent"  method="POST">
       <input type="submit" value="menubar" name="menubar" id="menubar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following function

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function () {
    PlaceContents();
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can write the same code like this :

resize function will run once the page has been loaded and also on resize event.

Good luck :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(window).resize(function(){    
        var Wheight = $(window).height();
        var Wwidth = $(window).width();
        var contentPos = Wwidth/4;
        var contentH = Wheight/5;
        //adjust menubar height
        $('#menubar').height(Wheight);
        //center main content
        $("#maincontent").css({top: contentH, left: contentPos, position:'absolute'});      
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: I believe you want a structure just like the one I've made for my site : please have a look http://www.redpeppermedia.in/

Comment: yes i do thats a nice site but can I have a look at your jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(window).resize(function(){    
        var Wheight = $(window).height();
        var Wwidth = $(window).width();
        var contentPos = Wwidth/4;
        var contentH = Wheight/5;
        //adjust menubar height
        $('#menubar').height(Wheight);
        //center main content
  $("#maincontent").css({top: contentH, left: contentPos, position:'absolute'});      
    });
});
```